# C++ how would one simplify this template so that it is not specialized?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, one-definition-rule, temple

I've attempted to build a template to compare floats or doubles based on https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/ for C++.  That version requires that the epsilon value be passed to the code but I'd like to use the default FLT_EPSILON, FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX, DBL_EPSILON, DBL_MIN, and DBL_MAX for the system and available in float.h.

Is there a way to use the typename in a statements like:

```
T epsilon;
if ( T == DBL_TYPE ) epsilon = DBL_EPSILON
else epsilon = FLT_EPSILON  ????
```

This would make the routine so I don't have to specialize it which is causing an One Definition Rule (ODR) problem.

I'm new to templates so I don't know how to ask questions.

```
template <typename T>
bool IsNearEqual( T test_1, T test_2 )
{
    if ( test_1 == test_2 ) return true;
    return false;
}

template <>
bool IsNearEqual( float test_1, float test_2 )
{
    const float FLT_NORMAL = ( (long)1 << 23 ) * FLT_EPSILON;
    if ( test_1 == test_2 )
    { // shortcut, handles infinities
        return true;
    }
    float test_1Abs = dfAbs( test_1 );
    float test_2Abs = dfAbs( test_2 );
    float test_1_2AbsDif = dfAbs( test_1 - test_2 );
    float test_1_2Sum = test_1Abs + test_2Abs;

    if ( test_1 == 0 || test_2 == 0 || test_1_2Sum < FLT_NORMAL )
    { // test_1 or test_2 is zero or both are extremely close to it relative error is less meaningful here
        return test_1_2AbsDif < ( FLT_EPSILON * FLT_NORMAL );
    }
    else
    { // use relative error
        return test_1_2AbsDif / dfMin( test_1_2Sum, FLT_MIN ) < FLT_EPSILON;
    }
    return false;
}
template <>
bool IsNearEqual( double test_1, double test_2 )
{
    const double DBL_NORMAL = ( (long long)1 << 52 ) * DBL_EPSILON;

    if ( test_1 == test_2 )
    { // shortcut, handles infinities
        return true;
    }
    double test_1Abs = dfAbs( test_1 );
    double test_2Abs = dfAbs( test_2 );
    double test_1_2AbsDif = dfAbs( test_1 - test_2 );
    double test_1_2Sum = test_1Abs + test_2Abs;

    if ( test_1 == 0 || test_2 == 0 || test_1_2Sum < DBL_NORMAL )
    { // test_1 or test_2 is zero or both are extremely close to it relative error is less meaningful here
        return test_1_2AbsDif < ( DBL_EPSILON * DBL_NORMAL );
    }
    else
    { // use relative error
        return test_1_2AbsDif / dfMin( test_1_2Sum, DBL_MAX ) < DBL_EPSILON;
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
T dfMin( T test_1, U test_2 )
{
    T out;
    out = test_1;
    if ( out > test_2 ) out = (T)test_2;

    return out;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
T dfMax( T test_1, U test_2 )
{
    T out;
    out = test_1;
    if ( test_2 > out ) out = (T)test_2;

    return out;
}

template <typename T>
T dfAbs( T test )
{
    T out;
    out = test;
    if ( test < 0.0 ) out = -test;

    return out;
}
```

Thanks,
RONC

Comment: You mean `std::numeric_limits<T>::espilon()`? All the constants `DLB_NORMAL` and `DLB_EPSILON` and etc are all macros from C world, use `std::numeric_limits` in C++. What exactly is your question about? How is the code presented related to the question? Why isn't the function `IsNearEqual` just a template with two arguments, type and the number of bits to shift? What is the point of `dfAbs` and `dfMax`, why not use `std::abs` and `std::max`?

Comment: What is the point of calculating a minimum with a maximum `dfMin( test_1_2Sum, DBL_MAX )`?

Comment: Did you look at the reference from where I started? I guess I should have duplicated what is in the article at the link. The question I'm asking is whether I can use the typename in a c type statement?

Comment: But what for? Why not just use `std::numeric_limits::epsilon()`? Why not write generic code? Why duplicate the same statements twice `float test1_Abs =` vs `double test1_Abs =`, why not just `T test1_Abs = std::abs(test_1)`?

Comment: Did you mean to use `FLT_MIN` or `FLT_MAX` in your first function?

Comment: In the original code you have `Float.MIN_NORMAL`. Your `FLT_NORMAL` is not equal to it, it is just `1.f`. Use `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code with a little SFINAE and use of `std::numeric_limits` as suggested in the comments.

```c++
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>{}>* = nullptr>
bool IsNearEqual(T test_1, T test_2) {
  using nl = std::numeric_limits<T>;

  const T NORMAL = ((long)1 << nl::digits) * nl::epsilon();
  if (test_1 == test_2) {  // shortcut, handles infinities
    return true;
  }
  float test_1Abs = dfAbs(test_1);
  float test_2Abs = dfAbs(test_2);
  float test_1_2AbsDif = dfAbs(test_1 - test_2);
  float test_1_2Sum = test_1Abs + test_2Abs;

  if (test_1 == 0 || test_2 == 0 ||
      test_1_2Sum < NORMAL) {  // test_1 or test_2 is zero or both are extremely
                               // close to it relative error is less meaningful
                               // here
    return test_1_2AbsDif < (nl::epsilon() * NORMAL);
  } else {  // use relative error
    return test_1_2AbsDif / dfMin(test_1_2Sum, nl::max()) < nl::epsilon();
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I had to add #include <type_traits> for it to compile but it seems to work.

Comment: Shouldn't   const float NORMAL = ( (long)1 << nl::digits() ) * nl::epsilon();             be                const T NORMAL = ( (long)1 << nl::digits() ) * nl::epsilon();   ??      Will (long)1  need to be    (long long)1 for double  ??             I have so much to learn about C++.      Thanks,  RONC

Comment: Also had to #define NOMINMAX  as first in the project.  Something about max() from Limits and max(a,b,c)  macros.

Comment: @Ronc 1) `nl::digits()` should be `nl::digits`, it is not a function. 2) For `double`, `digits` is `53`, not `52`, so you might want to subtract `1` from it. 3) Size of `long` is implementation defined (e.g. it is `32` bits on 64-bit Windows, but `64` bits on 64-bit Linux), so `long long` should be used for portability. 4) To avoid a collision with a macro name you can also write `(nl::max)()`.

Comment: Is SFINAE just another name for KLUDGE?

Comment: This is my final version I hope.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final version, I hope.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>

template <class T, std::enable_if_t < std::is_floating_point<T>{} > * = nullptr >
bool IsNearEqual( T test_1, T test_2 )
{
    using nl = std::numeric_limits<T>;

    const T NORMAL = (T)( (long long)1 << nl::digits ) * nl::epsilon();
    if ( test_1 == test_2 )
    {  // shortcut, handles infinities
        return true;
    }
    T test_1Abs = dfAbs( test_1 );
    T test_2Abs = dfAbs( test_2 );
    T test_1_2AbsDif = dfAbs( test_1 - test_2 );
    T test_1_2Sum = test_1Abs + test_2Abs;

    if ( test_1 == 0 || test_2 == 0 || test_1_2Sum < NORMAL )
    {  // test_1 or test_2 is zero or both are extremely
       // close to it relative error is less meaningful here
        return test_1_2AbsDif < ( nl::epsilon() * NORMAL );
    }
    else
    {  // use relative error
        return test_1_2AbsDif / dfMin( test_1_2Sum, (nl::max)() ) < nl::epsilon();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Changed float to T for test_1Abs, test_2Abs, test_1_2AbsDif, and test_1_2Sum.

Also (long)1 to (long long)1 .

Still not sure whether NORMAL should use nl::digits or nl::digits - 1 .   ?????????????

Thanks for the help @0x499602D2 and @Evg .

RONC